# Cartan's magic formula and geometric product

Tags: smooth-manifolds, geometric-algebras

Cartan's formula say's $L_X = d \circ i_X + i_X \circ d$ while in geometric algebra, we have $ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b$. These formula's seem similar to me. Especially, because the first is about k-forms, which are dual to multivectors, which the second is about. Furthermore, we also have $d \circ d=0$, and $a \wedge a = 0$. Are these similarities just coincidences, or this there some connection between them?

Comment: This little [gem](https://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~clifford/introduction/intro/node5.html) explains what the point is with the geometric product $ab\,:$ It decomposes it into a symmetric part (scalar product) and an antisymmetric part (bivector). As long as you don't tell me where those symmetries (anti symmetries) are in $L_X$ I see few relationships if at all. The Lie derivative of a one form also has no grading: $d(i_X\omega)$ is a one form and $i_X(d\omega)$ is a one form.